# Reading from a .txt. file in Java, save the results in an ArrayList and compare the characters

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a Hangman game, I cannot figure out a way to store the words in an array and compare it to the user input.

I have used a buffer reader, a randomizer and it works, it randomizes the words and shows them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileInputStream textFile;
    BufferedReader readWords;

    // Creates a string array
    ArrayList<String> arrayWordList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Read in the text file and randomize the words

    try {
        textFile = new FileInputStream("dictionary.txt");
        readWords = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textFile));
        String line = readWords.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            arrayWordList.add(line);
            line = readWords.readLine();
        }
        textFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    int arrayIntNumber = rand.nextInt(arrayWordList.size());

    // Initialize the GUI
    new HangGUI();

    System.out.println(arrayWordList.get(arrayIntNumber));

}
```

I should add a keylistener I guess as well as store the right letters in a char OR a string array, I'm not sure...

Then I need to convert the string array that contains the right words into a string and then compare the string with the letter the user inputs by using charAt(i) I guess?

This is my GUI-class for the Hangman:

```
public class HangGUI extends JFrame {
JPanel panel, guessLeftPanel, statusPanel, guessPanel, missPanel;
JLabel guessLeftLabel, guessCountLabel, currentStatus, guess, misses;
JTextField statusText, guessText, missesText;

// Create two arrays
String[] arrayRightWord;
String[] arrayHiddenWord;

String[] getGuess = new String[1];
String missedGuesses = "";


public HangGUI() {

    /* GUI */

    // Creates the menu bar
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    // Creates the game menu and add it to the game menu
    JMenu gameMenu = new JMenu("Game");
    menuBar.add(gameMenu);

    // Creates the game menu, the items and add it to the menu's
    JMenuItem startGame = new JMenuItem("Start");

    JMenuItem quitGame = new JMenuItem("Quit");
    gameMenu.add(startGame);
    gameMenu.add(quitGame);

    // Creates the options menu and add it to the menu bar
    JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");
    menuBar.add(optionsMenu);

    // Creates a button group consisting of radio buttons and add it to the
    // options menu
    ButtonGroup radioButtons = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton easy = new JRadioButton("Easy");
    JRadioButton medium = new JRadioButton("Medium");
    JRadioButton hard = new JRadioButton("Hard");

    radioButtons.add(easy);
    radioButtons.add(medium);
    radioButtons.add(hard);
    optionsMenu.add(easy);
    optionsMenu.add(medium);
    optionsMenu.add(hard);

    // Creates the main panel
    panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1, 5, 5));
    // Creates the label's and textfield's
    // Creates guesses left panel, label and text field
    guessLeftPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 5, 5));
    guessLeftLabel = new JLabel("Guesses left: ");
    guessCountLabel = new JLabel();

    // guessCountLabel.setText("sss");

    // ActionListener that doesn't do anything at the moment
    easy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int difficulty = 10;
            guessCountLabel.setText("" + difficulty);
        }
    });

    // ActionListener that doesn't do anything at the moment
    medium.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int difficulty = 7;
            guessCountLabel.setText("" + difficulty);
        }
    });

    // ActionListener that doesn't do anything at the moment
    hard.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int difficulty = 5;
            guessCountLabel.setText("" + difficulty);
        }
    });

    // Creates Current status panel and texfield
    statusPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
    currentStatus = new JLabel("Current status: ");
    statusText = new JTextField();
    statusText.setEditable(false);

    /*
     * createRightWord(arrayRandom());
     * 
     * 
     * statusText.setText(returnHiddenWordtoString());
     */

    // Creates the Guess panel and text field
    guessPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
    guess = new JLabel("Guess: ");
    guessText = new JTextField();
    guessText.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(1));

    // Creates the Misses panel and text field
    missPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
    misses = new JLabel("Misses: ");

    missesText = new JTextField();
    missesText.setEditable(false);
    // Make the label's, textfield's, menu and panel visible
    add(menuBar);
    add(panel);

    guessLeftPanel.add(guessLeftLabel);
    guessLeftPanel.add(guessCountLabel);
    statusPanel.add(currentStatus);
    statusPanel.add(statusText);
    guessPanel.add(guess);
    guessPanel.add(guessText);
    missPanel.add(misses);
    missPanel.add(missesText);

    panel.add(guessLeftPanel);
    panel.add(statusPanel);
    panel.add(guessPanel);
    panel.add(missPanel);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

    // Creates the frame and sets the menu bar
    setSize(400, 200);
    setTitle("Hangman");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    /*
     * guessHandler guesshandler = new guessHandler();
     * guessText.addActionListener(guesshandler);
     */

    // Construct a new class that handles Quit's the game
    quitHandler quithandler = new quitHandler();
    quitGame.addActionListener(quithandler);

    // Construct a new class that handles Starting the game
    startHandler starthandler = new startHandler();
    startGame.addActionListener(starthandler);

}

private class quitHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent quitEvent) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private class startHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent startEvent) {

        guessText.getText();
        System.out.println("Hej");
    }
}
```

So basically I'm wondering how to store the words from the textfile, which type of array I should use and how to compare the user's ONE letter input against one character of the correct word.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList, which you are already using, is probably the right way to store your Strings from the text file. Not that performance is the most important part of a program, but the fact that you are randomly picking an array index means that ArrayList is a good match since its lookup is instant (as opposed to LinkedList, which would require iterating the list).

To compare letter by letter, you will want to use either substring (and equals) or charAt. For example:

```
String hiddenWord = "foo";
char guessedLetter = 'f';
for(int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++) {
  if(hiddenWord.charAt(i) == guessedLetter) {
    System.out.println("Matched character: " + i);
  }
}
```

or

```
String hiddenWord = "foo";
String guessedLetter = "f";
for(int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++) {
  if(hiddenWord.substring(i, i + guessedLetter.length()).equals(guessedLetter)) {
    System.out.println("Matched substring: " + i);
  }
}
```

The cool thing about substrings is that if you ever want to match more than one letter, then you can use the same code. So you could find all instances of "fo" in "foofooffo" (3 instances).

You should note that `String` uses `.equals` for comparison and `char` uses `==`. This is because char is a primitive type and you are comparing the byte code values of the characters directly for equality. Strings are objects and their "value" would actually be their address in memory. So "foo" == "foo" would return false because the two Strings are different objects occupying different addresses in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're well on your way.

What you currently have is an `ArrayList` of phrases (I'm assuming each line in the text file contains a single phrase).  What you need to do is tokenize each phrase and store the resulting `String`s in a new `ArrayList`.  Something similar to this:

```
//untested pseudoish code
ArrayList<String> hangmanWord = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String phrase : arrayWordList){
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(phrase);
    while ( st.hasMoreElements() ){
       hangmanWord.add(st.nextElement());
    }
}
```

Then each time the user enters a `Character`, loop through your `hangmanWord` ArrayList, checking whether or not each item (String) in the list contains that Character or not.

One way to do this last part is using the `String` `.contains()` method [(which under the hood implements the `indexOf` method)](http://www.coderanch.com/t/473244/java/java/String-String-indexOf):

```
//more untested pseudo code 
for (String item : hangmanWord){
    if ( item.contains(guessText) ){
        //let user guess again
    }else{
        //decrement number of user tries left
        //if user has more tries let them go again
    }
 }
```

Also, I would probably store the `missedGuesses` in an ArrayList, right now it seems as though you are storing them in a single `String`, I would think storing them in an ArrayList would be easier than using one `String`.